How best (or where) to display high megapixel images on the web?
I have done a number of panoramic images, combining 3-20 images to make final photos of sometimes 400mp. I want to be able to display these online and be able to show the overall image and the detail that it contains.
I have tried searching here and didn't find anything, but that could be due to my newness here and how to utilize search properly. I have also done lots of Google search, but haven't really found anything that fits or works.

Are you a web developer or are you just looking for a "non-techie" solution that "just works"?

Thanks for the replies. I am not using a website where I can incorporate javascript or plugins of any sort. I did however find ZoomHub which lets me upload a large photo and they give me a small link that I can include in the caption of a photo. Not the greatest, but it works very well for display and does not have (so far) any big ads or things pointing to ZoomHub, just a clean link and display.

You need a JavaScript that.

Displays the panorama.
Allow you to do some zoom-in.

Googling it shows something like:

https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/#Home
https://photo-sphere-viewer-3.netlify.app/markers
https://navermaps.github.io/maps.js.en/docs/tutorial-6-panorama-zoomcontrol.example.html

You need to know a bit of programming and Web design to implement them.
I think they are limited in the zooming capability. To make an extreme zoom-in, you probably need some layering, where the lower-resolution images load first, and then the higher resolution.
Some other search with the word gigapixel
https://www.google.com/search?q=gigapixel+panorama+JavaScript+viewer
This viewer seems to load higher resolution images than the original loaded.
https://pannellum.org/

There are some image formats such as Deep Zoom that include tiles of your image at various resolutions, you can either use a service such as ZoomHub/Zoomable or you can convert & upload to a number of sites.
OpenSeaDragon has an open source JavaScript that you can potentially include or reference on your web page, one nice example here.

I understand your goal is just an easy to use viewer.  I think the DeepZoom plugin from PhotoSwipe fits exactly what you are looking for.  It is optimized for both desktop and mobile view.
Demo:
https://dimsemenov.github.io/photoswipe-deep-zoom-plugin/
Github: https://github.com/dimsemenov/photoswipe-deep-zoom-plugin

The problem with that script is that it does not have the panorama-viewer function.
